# drawingLines in java using Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Heres an example of a method to draw 1 line passing in two points

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
   Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D)comp; 
   comp2D.drawLine(0,60,100,60);
 }
```

Im trying to pass in a constructor for the points but when I go to run it in main I cannot figure what value I should pass in for comp when I call paintComponent

```
public class DrawLines{
      public void paintComponent(Graphics comp,int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
           Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D)comp; 
           comp2D.drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1);
      }

     public static void main(String[]args){
          drawLine(?,100,200,200,300);
     }
}
```

What should I pass in at the ?

Comment: Where's the rest of your graphics code? This is a Swing app?

Answer (score 4):

You need a `Graphics` (will normally be a  `Graphics2D` instance when using Swing) object, which gives you some context to actually draw with. Take a look at your main class... You want to draw a line, but what do you have to draw on? There isn't magically gonna be some window or canvas that pops up to draw on, you'll need to set that stuff up.

I suggest checking the [Java Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). That is, if you're already reasonably well versed in Java. If not, make sure your Java knowledge is first brought up to a decent level.

Comment: Agree. The OP has to read the tutorials. This is not something you can guess at and hope it works.

Comment: I suspect he might wish to start out with the general trails, though, since he's talking about a constructor when there plainly isn't one. Well, apart from the default.

Comment: Yeah I understand I need something to draw on I should have included all my main code sorry `import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class line extends JPanel{
 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(0,0,90,90);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.add(new line());
 
 
    jf.setSize(500,500);
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }
}`

Comment: That kind of makes a big difference. You're original code makes you come across as someone who doesn't even know the basics. Maybe you should update your post.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to give your class two Point fields, either that or four int fields, x1, y1, x2, y2, pass the values used to initialize these fields in your constructor, and then most important, **use the value held in these fields when doing your drawing.**

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LinePanel extends JPanel {
   private Point p1; // java.awt.Point objects
   private Point p2;

   // TODO: create constructor that accepts
   // and updates the two points

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g); // don't forget this!

      // TODO: Change the method below so that it uses
      // the two points to do the drawing with
      // rather than use hard coded magic numbers.
      g.drawLine(0, 0, 90, 90);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(500, 500);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JFrame jf = new JFrame();
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jf.add(new LinePanel()); // TODO: add parameters to constructor call.
      // jf.setSize(500, 500);
      jf.pack();
      jf.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: this can't hurt: 
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: @Chris: yep. But why stop there. added a getPreferredSize override to the JPanel and pack() to the JPanel. :)